# Preserving session data between requests using PHP's SoapClient

Tags: php, web-services, session

I have developed an ASP.NET Web Service that performs queries to a database. Now I am developing a PHP Web site that consumes the Web Service for anything that requires access to the database. I have written the following function which creates a new SoapClient to consume the Web Service:

```
function get_soap_client()
{
    if (!file_exists('wsdl_path.txt')
        return NULL;

    if (!$file = fopen('wsdl_path.txt', 'r'))
        return NULL;

    $path = fgets($file);
    fclose($file);

    return new SoapClient($path);
}
```

I have already tested this function as means to get a client to a *stateless* Web Service, and it does work. For example, this is my Web site's login function (whose control flow is not affected by state):

```
function try_login($user, $pass)
{
    $client = get_soap_client();

    // ASP.NET Web Services encapsulate all inputs in a single object.
    $param = new stdClass();
    $param->user = $user;
    $param->pass = $pass;

    // Execute the WebMethod TryLogin and return its result.
    // ASP.NET Web Services encapsulate all outputs in a single object.
    return $client->TryLogin($param)->TryLoginResult;
}
```

Which in turn calls the following WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public bool TryLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    SqlParameter[] pars = new SqlParameter[2];
    pars[0] = new SqlParameter("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    pars[0].Value = user;
    pars[1] = new SqlParameter("@Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    pars[1].Value = pass;

    // The Stored Procedure returns a row if the user and password are OK.
    // Otherwise, it returns an empty recordset.
    DataTable dt = Utilities.RetrieveFromStoredProcedure('[dbo].[sp_TryLogin]', pars);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) // Wrong user and/or password
    {
        Context.Session.Abandon();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

However, I don't know whether the Web Service's `Context.Session` data is preserved between consecutive requests made from `SoapClient` objects retrieved by `get_soap_client()`. So I have the following questions:

1. Is the Web Service's `Context.Session` data preserved between consecutive requests made from a `SoapClient` object retrieved by `get_soap_client()`?
2. Is the Web Service's `Context.Session` data preserved between consecutive requests made from *different* `SoapClient` objects retrieved on the fly as I need them?
3. If the answer to the previous question is "no", is there any way to serialize the `SoapClient`'s session data into a PHP state variable?

Comment: by "state information" do you mean the current $_SESSION data?

Comment: No. I actually meant the Web Service's `Context.Session` data. I want to keep as little data as possible in PHP's `$_SESSION` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you mean is it sending the SESSION ID. I imagine you'll need to call __setCookie manually to set a cookie with the SESSION ID to your web service.

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php